# Allow only numeric password in ASP.NET Core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a problem with ASP.NET Core identity. In the system I have designed, I need to allow the user to enter only a numeric password but I don't know how it possible with ASP.NET Core identity. I attempted all these but none of them didn't work.

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            setupAction.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
            setupAction.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            setupAction.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            setupAction.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            setupAction.Password.RequiredLength = 0;
            setupAction.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            setupAction.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        }).
        AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator>().
        AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>().
        AddSignInManager().
        AddUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
```

Also, I wrote a new password validator and register that to DI but it still doesn't work

```
 AddPasswordValidator<CustomPasswordValidator>()
```

This is my custom password validator

```
public class CustomPasswordValidator : IPasswordValidator<User>
{
    public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<User> manager, User user, string password)
    {
        Regex optionalAlphabetAndNumbersRegex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]+.{8}");

        if (optionalAlphabetAndNumbersRegex.IsMatch(password))
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Success);
        else
            return Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
            {
                Code = "Invalid Password",
                Description = "invalid password. password must be numeric or alphabetical or both"
            }));
    }
}
```

I know "only numeric password' isn't secure and strength but in this system, I need it.

Please help me!

Comment: I'm confused - your narrative talks about "numeric only", but your code clearly seems to be expecting alphanumeric. Which is your actual requirement?

Comment: CustomPasswordValidator  is working or not

Comment: well, I don't know how to write that these are just tested to find the correct answer. I need "only numeric password"

Comment: Note that `AddPasswordValidator` literally *adds* another password validator. It does not replace the default one that checks the password options. You do want to disable `RequireNonAlphanumeric` there, otherwise it will require symbols in the password.

Comment: @poke  I disable `RequireNonAlphanumeric` to **False** but still give warning "Invalid password"

Comment: Please check your server logs for details, the password validator will log out the actual reason why the password is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I found what's wrong with my code and I fixed it. I don't even need that `CustomPasswordValidator` and just set up these IdentityOptions and work fine.

```
 public IdentityBuilder AddIdentityService<TUser, TKey, TContext>() where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey> where TContext : DbContext where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        return _services.AddIdentityCore<TUser>(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            setupAction.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
            setupAction.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            setupAction.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            setupAction.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            setupAction.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
            setupAction.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            setupAction.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        }).
        AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>().
        AddSignInManager().
        AddUserManager<UserManager<TUser>>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in code:

1. First

   setupAction.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;

This will make sure you need to add special characters(NonAlphanumeric).

2. Second

   Regex optionalAlphabetAndNumbersRegex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]+.{8}");

Regular expression requires alpha numeric mandatory.

Please correct these if you require number only as you stated in requirements